# PlotView size in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, viewcontroller

I'm using the OxyPlot API to make graphs in iOS. I have a ViewController where I graph should be plot there. The PlotView is also a view so after plot the graph a do the following line to show the graph:

this.View = plotView;

The issue is that the graph is fitting up the entire screen and I don't want that. I wanna make it smaller. I have already looked for it but I didn't find a solution that works.

This is my code:

```
 PlotView plotView = new PlotView() {
Model = myLineChart.MyModel
```

};

```
myLineChart.AddPoint (0.0, 0.0);
myLineChart.AddPoint (1.0, 1.0);
this.View = plotView;
```